# How to check if Gaussian Process covariance model is good?

Tags: gaussian-process

I would like to generate some kind of plot from my data to see if my covariance kernel (square exponential) is a good one. I only have one data sample, so how do I calculate the spatial covariance to see if it looks like the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Cross validation is the way to find if your model fits the data generating process well. As the Gaussian Processes are part of Bayesian methodology all the rules of Bayesian applies here.

But your case, one data point in not good enough for GP's or for that matter any Machine Learning model. And, kernels are function's of data points, I'm sorry but you would get nothing out of this.